# Devise rake db:migrate fails because of duplicate column in my User's table - Rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.1

This is the error I get when I am first installing Devise and running `rake db:migrate`:

```
==  AddDeviseToUsers: migrating ===============================================
-- change_table(:users)
rake aborted!
An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

SQLite3::SQLException: duplicate column name: email: ALTER TABLE "users" ADD "email" varchar(255) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL
```

Given that this is just test data, I could just delete that column in my db and re-run it, but that doesn't seem very Railsy - if only for the reason that it will making my staging server (the only other server with my app) out-of-sync with my `localhost`.

Also, what if there is a conflict with another column.

So given that this is the schema of my `User` table before running the migration, how should I handle this? With a migration of some sort that does a rename?

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: users
#
#  id         :integer         not null, primary key
#  email      :string(255)
#  f_name     :string(255)
#  l_name     :string(255)
#  username   :string(255)
#  role_id    :integer
#  picture    :string(255)
#  about_me   :string(255)
#  website    :string(255)
#  created_at :datetime
#  updated_at :datetime
#
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `rake db:rollback` and then try again. When you did it the first time it added the id column. and why are you adding `id   :integer  not null, primary key` it's automatic in rails.  It should look like this:

```
class CreateProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    create_table :products do |t|
      t.string :email
      t.text :f_name

      t.timestamps
    end
  end

  def down
    drop_table :products
  end
end
```

You can get more information here http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html

Comment: No what happened was I had my `User` model with that schema there before I ran the `db:migrate`. I even had a few users stored in the table with the existing information. However, now that I am trying to install Devise into an existing User model, I get this error. So yes, I know that an `:email` column exists. I just want it to either ignore it, or modify it the way it needs to be modified.

Comment: you can skip it but commenting our the line on your migration. Then after that, you run rake db:migrate again.

Comment: Yep same problem here and all I did was comment out the line where email table is created in the devise migration like so #t.string :email,              :null => false, :default => ""

Answer (score 18):

In the migration file generated by Devise, change the line

```
  t.string :email,              :null => false, :default => ""
```

for

```
  t.change :email, :string,     :null => false, :default => ""
```

So instead of trying to create a new email colum, the migration changes the existing one to the specifications of Devise.

Answer (score 3):

Resolving this error is simple

1. if you already run the "`rake db:migrate`" i suggest run `rake db:rollback`"
2. Go to "`timestamp_add_devise_to_whatever.rb` and comment out
3. `# t.string :email,              null: false, default: ""`
4. Next also comment this
5. `# add_index :users, :email,                unique: true`
6. Run `rake db:migrate` and your good to go. :)

Comment: you're awesome- this works great- stackoverflow always has the worst answer as the selected one- this is a bug of society!

Answer (score 2):

I hit the same thing adding devise to an existing DB. This fixed it for me:

Modify the autogenerated devise migration:

```
t.rename :email, :email_old   # move my old email field out of the way 
... 
#add_index :users, :email, :unique => true  ## comment out unique index
```

Migrate the db.

Make the (new) email field data entries unique interactively w/ a SQL call:

```
update users set email=id;
```

Create another migration adding the unique constraint, and run it:

```
class UniquifyIndex < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
        add_index :users, :email, :unique => true
  end
```